# Change row values based in another row values (text)

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with usernames and their mail address. I want to update the values in usernames row to be the same as the mail address except the domain. For example, in jondoe@mailserver.com the user will be updated with "jondoe".

Is there any possibility to do this with a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
update t
    set username = substring_index(email, '@', 1);
```

I should note that different people can have the same email base name on different domains.  So, you should be careful that you don't generate duplicates.

If that is a problem, then ask *another* question.

Comment: This query gave me a syntax error. I changed all the names for the ones corresponding to my tables and fields.

Comment: @manuel, Gordon Linoff will not achieve clairvoyance until he reaches 500k points. What if you *told us* what that error actually *was*? That would make it easier to help you. Was the error possibly `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry...`? :-) ).

Comment: @isemi . . . The error was stupid.  I left out the third argument to `substring_index()`, and it is now fixed.